# Angular - Cannot set property of undefined in delegate func

Tags: angular, delegates

I am calling a service through a common method that executes two functions, one on success and one on failure. The call is executed correctly, however within the success function I have a variable that I want to assign with the value of the service result, but it happens that it generates the error "Cannot set property 'resultService' of undefined". Below I add the code snippet that I am using

CallWS.Service.ts

```
export class CallWSService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  callGetMethodExample(urlService: string, responseFunc: (responseParam: any) => any, doInError?: (outService: any) => any) {
    return this.http.get(urlService).subscribe(
      data => (responseFunc(data)),
      error => (doInError(error))
    )
  }
}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private invokeService: CallWSService) { }
  resultService: object;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.invokeService.callGetMethodExample("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees",this.responseFunc);
  }

  responseFunc (result: any) : any {
    console.log(result);
    this.resultService = result;
    console.log(this.resultService);
  }

  doInError (result: any) : any {
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

The error that occurs is that when trying to assign the value of the resultService variable it generates the following error and I do not understand why this happens

[Error generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRjS8.png)

It seems that it does not recognize the variable and the error is generated

Answer (score 0):

the problem is typical js problem - loosing of context. to fix it use arrow functions:

```
this.invokeService.callGetMethodExample(url, result => this.responseFunc(result));
```

with this piece of code `responseFunc` won't loose a context

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for the answer. In effect, with the use of the arrow function, the problem stopped happening